# Mastermind permutationst

Tags: combinatorics

We talked about Mastermind game in the beginning of semester. Recall
that mastermind codes consist of an ordered row of four colors and opponent tries to
guess the code. (For instance, RED BLUE BLUE ORANGE is one code; BLUE RED
BLUE ORANGE is a different code.) There are six different colors to choose from. How
many potential Mastermind codes have 2 or 3 pegs the same color (i.e., one pair or one
trio, but not two pairs)?

---

The answer would be the number of codes with 2 like pegs plus the number of codes with 3 like pegs, which I believe is:

(4C2 ways to arrange the two) x (6 choices of color which occurs twice) x (5C2 choices of other two colors)

+

(4 ways to arrange the three) x (6 choices of color which occurs three times) x (5 choices of other color)

This would give me 360 + 120 = 480 codes.

First of all, is this correct? If it is, can someone give me a brief explanation of why? Why would we be using nCr instead of nPr, since order would matter in this case?

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer for three pegs of the same color is correct.  However, your answer for having two pegs of the same color is not since you failed to take the order of the other colors into account.

There are six ways of choosing the repeated color, $\binom{4}{2}$ ways of selecting two of the four locations for that color, five choices for the color of the leftmost open position, and four choices for the color of the remaining position, which yields
$$6 \cdot \binom{4}{2} \cdot 5 \cdot 4 = 720$$
possible ways to have two pegs of the same color without having two pairs.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So that would be the same as having the last term be 5P2, not 5C2, correct?

Comment: That is correct.